# Insert 100 million integer into Redis performance is very bad

Tags: redis

I am using Spring app to insert 1, 2, 3, ..., 100000000 into Redis. But if I do hashOpertatios.put(“TestKey”, i, i), i is integer, I have been waiting more than half hours, insertion is not completed, I don’t know when it will be completed. But if I use hashOperation. put(“TestKey”, 123, map), but I received the Out of memory error. (map is HashMap<Integer, Integer>, which I already inserted 1, 2, 3, ..., 100 millions)

What should I do next? How I can insert 100 millions integer into Redis quickly.

Answer (score 0):

did you use pipeline? https://redis.io/topics/pipelining

it will help increasing the throughput.

Comment: I did not find any helpful tutorial about how to use pipeline within Spring boot application. Can you share a one or provide some sample code?

Comment: try this https://github.com/redis/jedis/wiki/AdvancedUsage#pipelining